# Background Colour not showing

Tags: css, html, background

I am having trouble changing the background colour of my website in CSS.

```
body  {background-color: #c7daf9‬;}
```

That is currently at the top of my CSS file which is working. When I inspect element on chrome, it shows that value is not being used, as it is crossed out on the side where it shows the css.

I can't seem to understand why this would be.

You can see a demo at [www.dweeman.com/eb/sitetemplate.html](http://www.dweeman.com/eb/sitetemplate.html)

There is one other section which is giving values to my body, but even when I put the bg colour in there it doesn't work.

Comment: Pretty weird.  You can set background with document.body.style.backgroundColor = 'blue', but not the hex you have in css.

Comment: i look ing for your problen an other way but old is <body bgcolor="#c7daf9‬">

Comment: I'm hoping to keep all formatting within the css document if I can help it.

A quick test of adding the <body bgcolor="#c7daf9‬"> made the background some kind of weird orange yellow. But http://www.colorhexa.com/c7daf9 clearly shows it's a light blue, which is what I want.

Comment: @dweeman This is really interesting issue... First I thought it was comments which was ignoring the block but I was wrong

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is an illegal invisible character in that CSS line, right between the 9 and the semicolon.

It seems to be the Unicode Character 'POP DIRECTIONAL FORMATTING' (U+202C), [which you can read more about here](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/202c/index.htm).

To see it in action, paste your code into a text editor, click next to the A (so it has a blinking "I" cursor), and start pressing the right arrow key. You'll notice that right after the 9, it takes two right arrows presses to reach the semicolon.

The solution: Just backspace the color entry and type it out again.

Comment: Beautiful, thanks! I copied it over facebook from a friend so that must be where it happened.

Answer (score 0):

I think it should't matter specifying your color code in Lowercase, but changing it to Uppercase worked for me. so you can try and update your hex color code to Uppercase.

```
<div class="with-lowercase"><p>dfd</p></div>
<div class="with-uppercase"><p>dfd</p></div>
.with-lowercase{
    background-color:#c7daf9‬;
}
.with-uppercase{
    background-color:#C7DAF9;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ramshinde/8Tj6H/4/